# Spring Security 4 reload intercept url runtime reload

Tags: tomcat, url, spring-security, intercept

Does anyone know a way to reload the intercept url config during runtime so that I don't have to restart Tomcat? I would like to urls configurable in the database.

Comment: Take a look at [using-boot-devtools - auto restart](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart) if you are using spring-boot

Comment: Unfortunately not using boot. Only thing spring in my java web app is spring security.